# How long until JxBrowser ships the latest version of Chromium (version 77)?

Tags: java, performance, web-component, chromium-embedded, jxbrowser

In September 2019 Chromium 77 was released, when will it be available in JxBrowser? It contains a lot more performance improvements and fixed security issues over the 69 version that is a bit over a year old, and the maximum version currently available in JxBrowser. It would give big improvements on running out Web Components inside JxBrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following answer from Teamdev via email:

"We are currently working on the next Chromium update. We plan to release a new JxBrowser version with an updated Chromium engine by December 2019. The Chromium version will be 77+."

Comment: I have since gotten an update stating that they are delayed in upgrading Chromium an that they need a minimum of 2 more months to complete the update. At the moment they are aiming towards Chromium 79 for the next update.